# Show code for specific block in cisco IOS conf mode?

Tags: cisco, router, ios

I work with Fortigate gear a lot and in the CLI it's possible to navigate to a node (say `config system global` then type in `show` and it will show me the configuration from that block.

In IOS I can't figure out how to do this, I know I can exit `conf term` mode and use `show run` but the configs can be very long.

Is it possible while in say:

```
router>en
router#conf t
router(config)#interf f0/1
```

To type a command that will show me only the config section like this:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 speed auto
 full-duplex
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is :

```
router# show running-config interface FastEthernet0/1
```

This will only display the configuration for port Fa0/1.

---

When you are in config mode, you can use the `do` keyword to call the `show` command :

```
router(config)# do show running-config interface FastEthernet0/1
```

Comment: Since he is in configuration mode you'll need to add "do" in front of the "show running-conf" command

Comment: @Mike Pennington I've just edited my answer with this just a few second before i see your comment ;)

Comment: Apologies I'm responding from my phone so I don't get notifications about edits

Comment: That's the ticket! Cheers bud :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
show running-config | section ?
```

e.g.

```
show running-config | section router bgp
```

It works similar to the `include` statement, but also lists all the sub-commands.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful tool is the pipe command `|` and `include`, so:

```
router# show running-config | include interface
```

would show you all lines in the running-config containing the word interface

Comment: `| begin` is also a useful feature in some cases : `show running-config | begin interface` ;)